# Difference between {} or = to give values in commands

Tags: command-line

Difference between `{}` or `=` to give values in latex commands.

Comment: Can you share some more detail about what you mean here?

Comment: You might mean the difference between the traditional, built in way using `\newcommand` or `\def` vs. keys such as pgf keys. At the surface they are very different, internally keys use `\def` (and its variants like `\edef`) in some clever ways.

Comment: please complete the post to contain an actual question. `{}` and `=` are different and there are very few places where you have a choice over which to use, so I can not guess what question you are asking here?

Comment: Taking into account that OP's author ask about LaTeX commands, it seems to me that he means commands for dimensions setting and difference between `\mydimen = 1pt` and `\setlength{\mydimen}{1pt}`. If that's so, there is no fundamental difference between this two notation. But more clarification needs.